# Extend a linear bounded functional on $C_0(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\phi:C_0(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{C}$ be a bounded linear functional and suppose $\mu$ is complex Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi(f)=\int fd\mu$ for every rational function $f$ over the field of complex numbers whose restriction to $\mathbb{R}$ belongs to $C_0(\mathbb{R})$. Show that the formula $\phi(f)=\int fd\mu$ holds for all $f\in C_0(\mathbb{R})$.

Hahn-Banach Theorem can extend a bounded linear functional, but it is not enough to conclude the result. Can anyone give a hint?

Definition of $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ is $C_0(\mathbb{R})=${f:continuous and if for every $\epsilon>0$ the set $\{x:|f(x)|\ge\epsilon\}$ is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint apply Stone Weirstrass, rational functions are dense in $C_0(R)$ if $f\in C_0(R)$, $(f_n)\rightarrow f$ is a sequence of rational functions which converges towards $f$, then $\phi(f)=lim\phi(f_n)$ since $\phi$ is bounded thus $\phi(f)=lim\int f_nd\mu=\int fd\mu$

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the definition of $C_0$, and I edited my question.

Comment: Thanks for help. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone–Weierstrass_theorem#Locally_compact_version), for people who need to see the Stone Weirstrass Theorem for locally compact space.